# PDO where + order by

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-order-by

Hi I'm trying to pull a list with names from a table in PDO with a given first letter and ordering it by ASC but get empty Arrays.

```
include('core/engine/login.php');
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$row = $con->prepare("SELECT title FROM ".$dbprefix."anime WHERE title= :title: ORDER BY title ASC");
$row->bindParam(':title', $aniprefix, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$row->execute();
$results = $row->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

} catch(PDOException $ex) {
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Question is? Errors are? Attempts were? Drive-by code dropping isn't my cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues to point out.

- In the SQL text, bind parameter placeholders start with a colon, but don't end with a colon.
- the equality comparison operator (**`=`**) does an exact comparison. To look for a partial match, you can use the `LIKE` comparison operator. For example, to find all rows that have `title` with a first character of `'T'`, you'd could use an predicate such as **`title LIKE 'T%'`**. Note that in the context of a `LIKE`, the `'%'` is a wildcard that matches zero, one or more of any characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = $con->prepare("SELECT title FROM ".$dbprefix."anime WHERE title LIKE :title ORDER BY title ASC");
$row->bindParam(':title', $aniprefix.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: @Lal Good point, I suggest the OP sees spencer7593's answer for an explanation. I can't beat that.